# How to specify python type hints for complex package as opencv or tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, types, opencv

I am building a python library and I writing a function like this:

```
def addimg(image) -> None:
```

now I want to specify the type of image as an OpenCV image (e.g., the result of cv2.readimg()). Is there an elegant way to do that?

The same question for PyTorch or TensorFlow tensors.

Otherwise, my library ends up with every second variable having no specified type and I think this looks really ugly.

Thank you very much!
Best,
Bernhard

Comment: The Python OpenCV bindings don't have the type info generated yet, it seems: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14590

Answer (score 9):

The type of an OpenCV image is a Numpy array (named `ndarray`):

```
>>> image = cv2.imread("my_image.png")
>>> type(image)
numpy.ndarray
```

So you can use:

```
from numpy import ndarray

def addimg(image: ndarray) -> None:
    ...
```

---

Update:

Numpy version 1.21 introduced [`numpy.typing.NDArray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html?highlight=typing#numpy.typing.NDArray), a generic version of `ndarray` that allows specifying the data type.

For example, if the image uses `uint8`:

```
from numpy import uint8
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def addimg(image: NDArray[uint8]) -> None:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV 4 (tested with 4.8.0.76) uses `cv2.typing.MatLike` as type for image objects in its definitions of `imread()` and other functions:

```
def imread(filename: str, flags: int = ...) -> cv2.typing.MatLike: ...
```

You can use `cv2.typing.MatLike`, which is defined as a union of Mat and ndarray, as type for custom image functions/objects when using OpenCV:

```
import cv2

def foo_image(image: cv2.typing.MatLike) -> cv2.typing.MatLike:
    # ... do something to image ...
    return image
```